# How to make the checkbox working properly in following scenario?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm using PHP, Smarty and jQuery for my website. In a smarty template I'm having few checkboxes upon which I'm working. For your reference following is my smarty code snippet regarding checkboxes.

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="groups_listing" style="{if $data.show_group=='on'}display:{else}display:none;{/if}">
     <tr>
     {if $all_groups}
     {assign var='i' value=0}
     {foreach from=$all_groups item="group"}
       {if $i%4 == 0}</tr><tr>{/if}
         <td valign="top" align="left" width="200">
           <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">
             <tr>
               <td>
               <input type="checkbox" name="parent_groups[]" id="{$group.parent_id}" id="{$group.parent_id}" onchange="check_subgroups(this.id, 'class_{$group.parent_id}');" value="{$group.parent_id}" {foreach from=$user_groups item=user_grp} {if $user_grp== $group.parent_id} checked="checked" {/if}{/foreach}>
               <label><strong>{$group.parent_name} </strong></label>
               <input type="hidden" name="main_groups[]" id="main_groups[]" value="{$group.parent_id}">
               </td>
             </tr>                       
             {foreach from=$group.subgroups item=subgroup}
             <tr>
               <td>
               <input type="checkbox" name="groups_{$group.parent_id}[]" class="class_{$group.parent_id}" onchange="uncheck_main_group('{$group.parent_id}'); return false;" value="{$subgroup.group_id}" style="margin-left:20px;" {foreach from=$user_groups item=user_grp} {$user_grp} {if $user_grp==$subgroup.group_id} checked="checked" {/if}{/foreach}> <label>{$subgroup.group_name}</label>
               </td>
             </tr>
             {/foreach}
           </table>  
           {assign var='i' value=$i+1}
         {/foreach}
       {/if}
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

The javascript functions are as follows:

```
function show_groups(check_box_id) 
{
    if ($(check_box_id).is(':checked')) {

        $('#groups_listing').show();

        } else {

        $('#groups_listing').hide();
        }
}

function check_subgroups(parent_id, class_name) { 
        var chk = document.getElementById(parent_id).checked;
        if(chk == true) 
            $('.'+jQuery.trim(class_name)).attr('checked', true);
        else
            $('.'+jQuery.trim(class_name)).attr('checked', false);
    }
```

The first javascript function named **show_groups()** works fine, noissue with that. My issue is with the second function named **check_subgroups()**. It also works fine initially after page load but later if I uncheck and again chech the parent checkbox it's not working. Also when I check all the child checkboxes one bu one then it is expected that the parent child box should automatically get checked and vice versa. This is not working in current situation. Can you help me in achieving this functionality. For your reference I'm attaching the screen shot of checkboxes with this question. You can see here in the question I've checked all the child check boxes under parent **Course** but the parent checkbox is not getting checked automatically. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Use prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of attr when manipulating checked state.  The link explains more.  This may not, of course, be the root of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you don't mind but I created a [jsFiddle Abstraction](http://jsfiddle.net/8q6M6/) for ensuring all children being checked toggles the parent to checked, rather than modifying your code exactly to give you an idea of one approach you might use.

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    <input type="checkbox" class="parent"/>
    <div class="childGroup">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child"/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="child"/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="child"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can use this jQuery to ensure your parent selects/deselects when the child group changes.

```
$('.child').on('change', function () {

    var $parent = $(this).closest('.parentDiv').find('input.parent'),
    $childCheckboxes = $(this).closest('.childGroup').find('.child');

    if ( $childCheckboxes.length === $childCheckboxes.filter(':checked').length ) {
        $parent.prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $parent.prop('checked', false);
    }

});
```

and to [toggle all children on parent toggle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xbcu/):

```
$('.parent').on('change', function () {

    var $children = $(this).closest('.parentDiv').find('.child');

    $children.prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));

});
```

Per your request, I've tried to put this into the context of your check_subgroups function:

```
function check_subgroups(parent_id, class_name) { 

    $parent = $('#' + parent_id);

    $childCheckboxes = $('.' + $.trim(class_name));

    $childCheckboxes.prop('checked', $parent.is(':checked')); 

}
```

And to toggle the parent when all children are selected:

```
function uncheck_main_group(parent_id) {

    var $parent = $('#' + parent_id);

    var $children = $('.class_' + $.trim(parent_id));

    if ( $children.length === $children.filter(':checked').length ) {
        $parent.prop('checked', true);   
    } else {
        $parent.prop('checked', false);   
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's working fine. But when I check the parent checkbox, all its corresponding child checkboxes are not getting checked. Only this issue is there otherwise it's working fine. Can you improvize your solution in order to achieve this.

Comment: It's the bottom set of javascript in the answer, also in the second [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xbcu/) I linked to.

Comment: I'm requesting you to convert your code into javascript in such a way that I can write into a function function check_subgroups(parent_id, class_name). Can you convert it please?

Comment: Understood, I've tried updating my answer with a block at the end, but as mentioned in the answer - if this doesn't work please recreate a jsFiddle with your code so I can get at any problems more easily.

Comment: :Thank you so much Ross. I don't have words to say thanks to you. Your javascript code is working absolutely fine but the vice versa is not working i.e. after manually selecting the child checkboxes one by one the parent checkbox is not geting checked automatically. So can you modify your function code accordingly, please?

Comment: Do you want a separate function or are you trying to use `check_subgroups` for both purposes?

Comment: I want a separate function to uncheck Take a name function uncheck_main_group(parent_id).

Comment: I've updated the answer with what I think you're looking for, see how that works.

Comment: :Your idea worked perfectly for me. Thank you so much Ross. I'm extremely thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('.'+jQuery.trim(class_name)).attr('checked', false);
```

use

```
$('.'+jQuery.trim(class_name)).removeAttr('checked');
```

It doesn't matter what is the value of checked attribute. If it **exists**, the checkbox is checked.

Comment: :Thanks for your answer but I think you have not got my issue clearly. I want to autocheck the parent check box after checking all the child boxes manualy one by one and vice versa. Can you help me in achieving this?

Comment: this is the code for check/uncheck main checkbox, when all checkbox below are the same state.

if($('.'+jQuery.trim(class_name)).not(':checked').size() == 0) {
 $("#"+parent_id).attr('checked', 'checked');
}
else if($('.'+jQuery.trim(class_name)+':checked').size() == 0) {
 $("#"+parent_id).removeAttr('checked');
}

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's not working fine. It is locking the parent checkbox so I'm not able to make the parent checkbox checked.